# How can i mutate a list in elixir which I am iterating using Enum.map ? or need opinion on using nested recursion

Tags: enums, elixir

I have two lists in elixir. One list (`list1`) has values which get consumed in another list (`list2`). So I need to iterate over `list2` and update values in `list1` as well as `list2`.

```elixir
list1 = [
  %{
    reg_no: 10,
    to_assign: 100,
    allocated: 50
  },
  %{
    reg_no: 11,
    to_assign: 100,
    allocated: 30
  },
  %{
    reg_no: 12,
    to_assign: 100,
    allocated: 20
  }
]

list2 = [
  %{
    student: student1,
    quantity: 60,
    reg_nos: [reg_no_10, reg_no_11]
  },
  %{
    student: student2,
    quantity: 40,
    reg_nos: [reg_no_11, reg_no_12]
  },
  %{
    student: student3,
    quantity: 30,
    reg_nos: nil
  }
]
```

I need to assign values from `list1` to `quantity` field of `list2` till `quantity` is fulfilled. e.g. `student1` `quantity` is `60` which will need `reg_no 10` and `reg_no 11`.

With `Enum.map` I cannot pass updated `list1` for 2nd iteration of `list2` and assign value reg_nos: `reg_no_11`, `reg_no_12`for `student2`.

So, my question is how can I send updated `list1` to 2nd iteration in `list2`?

I am using recursion to get quantity correct for each element in `list2`. But again, should I use recursion only to send updated `list1` in `list2`? With this approach, there will be 2 nested recursions. Is that a good approach?

Comment: Hi. Please show your code and explain what's not working how you want it to. From your question is seems like you actually have a working solution but want to know if it's "good". If that's true, then maybe the question would be a better fit for the Code Review stackexchange.

Comment: @PawełObrok It sounds like he has a working solution he wants to expand. That, is a feature request. And that's not within [Code Review's scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast, perhaps. As-is it is difficult to say what state the code is in and what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change values in a given list `x`, based on a list of values in another list `y`.

What you describe is not possible in a functional language due to immutability, but you can use a [`reduce`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) operation where `x` is the state or so-called "accumulator".

Below is an example where I have a ledger with bank accounts, and a list with transactions. If I want to update the ledger based on the transactions I need to reduce over the transactions and update the ledger per transaction, and pass the updated ledger on to the next transaction. This is the problem you are seeing as well.

As you can see in the example, in contrast to `map` you have a second parameter in the user-defined function (`ledger`). This is the "state" you build up while traversing the list of transactions. Each time you process a transaction you have a change to return a modified version of the state. This state is then used to process the second transaction, which in turn can change it as well.

The final result of a reduce call is the accumulator. In this case, the updated ledger.

```
  def example do
    # A ledger, where we assume the id's are unique!
    ledger = [%{:id => 1, :amount => 100}, %{:id => 2, :amount => 50}]
    transactions = [{:transaction, 1, 2, 10}]

    transactions
    |> Enum.reduce(ledger, fn transaction, ledger ->
      {:transaction, from, to, amount} = transaction

      # Update the ledger.
      Enum.map(ledger, fn entry ->
        cond do
          entry.id == from -> %{entry | amount: entry.amount - amount}
          entry.id == to -> %{entry | amount: entry.amount + amount}
        end
      end)
    end)
  end
```

Comment: Hello Christophe De Troyer, 

       Is there any way by which you can change value of amount as well and update it after every from and to operations ? I need to update amount where you are updating ledger and return it to the next transaction.
Lets assume, amount is current balance in bank, so this should get updated after every transaction.

Comment: Got it working using double recursion, I could update value of amount.